# Set the value of a radio button to be the text from the closest input text via jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a form where I am adding form elements dynamically. The elements I am adding are a text field and a radio button. Now, I want the value of the selected radio button to be the text the user has typed on the adjacent input box. Here is the JS:

```
var $node = "";
var varCount=0; 

$('body').on('click', '.removeVar', function(){        
    $(this).parent().remove();
    varCount--;
});
$('#addfld').on('click', function(){
    varCount++;
    $node = '<label for="losfldlbl[]">Field Name '+varCount+': </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="losfldlbl[]" id="losfldlbl[]" title="Custom field name cannot be blank" required=true placeholder="Field name'+varCount+'"/>'+
            'Is this the value field? &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="losvaluefld[]" id="losvaluefld[]" value=false />&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            '<span class="removeVar label label-important"><a id="removeFld" href="#" title="Click here to remove this field"><i class="icon-minus icon-white"></i></a></span>';

    $(this).parent().before($node);
});
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).prev().attr("value"));
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<form id='myForm'>
click on the yellow button custom fields &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='label label-warning'><a id='addfld' href='#' title='Click here to add a new field'><i class='icon-plus icon-white'></i></a></span>&nbsp;    
</form>
```

I have shared a [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pyj7K/1/). The problem is that I cannot get the value passed from the input text to the radio button's value.

Comment: Why can't you wait until the user is done adding elements to the form and grab everything then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting radio buttons and attaching your event handler before the radio buttons even exist on the page.

I'd recommend using `on` to delegate events for radio buttons added in the future:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'input:radio', function() {
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).prev().attr("value"));

    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Pyj7K/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer,if the user decides to click on the radio button before typing can we still get the text passed to the radio button's value

Comment: In that case it's empty string (`''`), unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: You are misunderstanding, can we add a handler also on the input fields? so that we avoid having an empty string when the user clicks the radio before typing the text?

Comment: @indago: Okay, how about just listening to the `change` event on the text input itself? http://jsfiddle.net/Pyj7K/3/

Comment: @Whitaker: I have tested your latest change and it is abit risky because it gives the wrong value to the wrong radio button,if i have selected the first radio button and i add another field if i type it will give the previous radio button the value of this new text field which is wrong, please check it out?

Comment: @indago: Are you sure? Use "inspect element" in your browser tools to see the updated value of the radio button.